# How to get Textbox value to a php variable within same php file with a button click (without submitting the form)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the textbox value with a button click (without form submission) and assign it to a php variable within the same php file. I tried AJAX, but, I don't know where I am making mistake. Sample code: 
File name: trialTester.php

```
<?php
 if(!empty($_POST))
 echo "Hello ".$_POST["text"];
 ?>
<html>
  <head>
   <title> Transfer trial </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <input type="textbox" id="scatter" name="textScatter">
 <button id="inlinesubmit_button" type="button">submit</button>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   function submitMe(selector)
   {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "",
      data: {text:$(selector).val()}
    });

   }
   $('#inlinesubmit_button').click(function(){
    submitMe('#scatter');
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ajax you can get the post value but by replacing the existing content.

See the code below, as all the content is pesent in the body tag, so we will replace the content present in this body through the response of ajax.

Copy & paste this code & let me know if you have any query.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
echo "Hello ".$_POST["text"];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Transfer trial </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<input type="textbox" id="scatter" name="textScatter">
<button id="inlinesubmit_button" type="button">submit</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   function submitMe(selector)
   {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: {text:$(selector).val()},
    success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    });

   }
   $('#inlinesubmit_button').click(function(){
    submitMe('#scatter');
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, this may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After doing the amendments, then also, I am not getting the results.

Comment: Your button Tag is also not closed correctly in html. Please correct it

Comment: I have updated the answer by modifying your code, hope now it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prateek for your help - Prateek Dwivedi

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to close `$(document).ready(function(){`.
2. Your AJAX posts `text` parameter, but in your PHP code you're accessing `textScatter`. Change that to `text`
3. It should be `<input type="text" id="scatter" name="textScatter">`, there is no `textbox` type.
4. You make an ajax request, so when it completes you need to display the results, e.g:

-

```
function submitMe(selector)
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: {text:$(selector).val()},
    success: function(newHtml) {
       $("body").html(newHtml);
    }
});
```

When you do `$.ajax` you specify the names of the POSTed parameters yourself, `name="textScatter"` is not taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After doing the amendments, then also, I am not getting the results.

Comment: Do you see any errors in developer console? Are there any PHP errors?